# jQuery MouseMove: fading of contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, timeout, mousemove

I have full-screen background images that I want to control via a "prev" and "next" arrow on the left and right side of my website.

**html**

```
<nav id="pagination">
    <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
    <a id="next" href="#"></a>
</nav>
```

**css (scss)**

```
#pagination {   
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;

    a { 
        display:block;
        position:fixed;
        top:45%;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;

        &#next {
            right:20px;
        }

        &#prev {
            left:20px;
        }
    }
}
```

So this gives me exactly what I want. I have a previous-image-link centered vertically on the left side of my page and a next-image-link centered vertically on the right side of my page.

I have the following JS (jquery) to fadeIn() and fadeOut() this navigation …

```
var c, p = $('#pagination');
$(document).on('mousemove',function() {
        p.fadeIn('fast');
        clearTimeout(c);
        c = setTimeout(function() {
            p.fadeOut('fast');
        }, 1000);
    });
```

This works just fine, however the `#pagination` also fadesOut() when I'm currently over a pagination link. Is it possible to exclude the links itself from this behaviour? I hope my explanation is not too weird. Again: Right now my pagination works like well-known video players. When not moving the mouse the pagination fades out - when moving the mouse the pagination fades in again.

But when I'm currently over one of the two links (`#prev` or `#next`) and don't move the mouse the `#pagination' fades out as well. I don't want that to happen. So when the mouse is hovering the two pagination links the pagination shouldn't fade out.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 var c;
 $('#pagination').('mousemove',function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    clearTimeout(c);
    c = setTimeout(function() {
        p.fadeOut('fast');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Does not work. And you might have got me wrong. I want the entire document to track the mousemove - so when moving the mouse on the document the "fadeIn()" function should always fire. However I just don't want to fadeOut() the `pagination` after the timeout when I'm currently hovering the `next` and `prev` link itself.